# Android NDK - how to create multiple bitmaps given only size (width and height)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am new at this - asking questions, android developement and NDK. I hope I am clear enough.

I need to be able to create multiple surfaces/bitmaps. 
e.g.

```
Surface s = new Surface (width, height)
```

- they can copy between each other
  s->copy (s2) copy surface s to s2 (including format conversion between RGBA and alpha-text surface and resizing/scaling)
- use fill (x, u, w, h, color) - fill rectangle with color (something like glClear)

As far as I understand you have only one ANativeWindow which is supplied to you by android_app->window variable and if I use EGL I can create upto 1 EGLSurface. I need to be able to create many surfaces (~ 100 for instance). How is this possible? And then blit all of them to the window framebuffer

There is also android/bitmap.h But I am not getting it exactly how to work with it. But it does not offer me API to create surface, just to get already created or something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can create bitmap through JNI calls:**

```
// setup bitmap class
jclass bitmap_class = (jclass)env->FindClass ("android/graphics/Bitmap");
// setup create method
jmethodID bitmap_create_method = env->GetStaticMethodID (bitmap_class, "createBitmap", "(IILandroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;");
// get_enum_value return jobject corresponding in our case to Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888. (the implentation is irrelevant here)
jobject bitmap_config_ARGB = get_enum_value ("android/graphics/Bitmap$Config", "ARGB_8888");
// Do not forget to call DeleteLocalRef where appropriate

// create the bitmap by calling the CreateBitmap method
// Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
jobject bitmap =  env->CallStaticObjectMethod (bitmap_class, bitmap_create_method, width, height, bconfig);

// at the end of course clean-up must be done
env->DeleteLocalRef (bitmap);
```

---

**You can access some bitmap properties and the raw pixels through the API in `android/bitmap.h`**

`AndroidBitmap_getInfo` gives information about format (`ARGB_8888` or alpha-only), dimensions, stride or pitch.

`AndroidBitmap_lockPixels` give the raw pixels. After finished manipulating the pixels one MUST call `AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels`

---

**To make `fill (color, dimension)`**

JNI can help. This can be written through JNI calls (I will use java because it is easier for me to write and clearer to read).

```
canvas.save ();
canvas.setBitmap (bitmap);
canvas.clipRect (left, top, right, bottom, Region.Op.REPLACE);
canvas.drawColor (color,  PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
canvas.restore ();
```

---

**To copy one bitmap over another one - `copy (src_bitmap, src_rect, dest_rect)`**

```
canvas.save ();
canvas.setBitmap (dest_bitmap);
canvas.clipRect (left, top, right, bottom, Region.Op.REPLACE);
canvas.drawBitmap (src_bitmap, src_rect, dest_rect, null);
canvas.restore ();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create [Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) and use the jnigraphics library (android/bitmap.h) or you can use multiple EGL textures.

Using Bitmaps you'll have to implement `fill` yourself, because Bitmap does only have pixel-based getters and setters (see [`setPixels(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixel%28int,%20int,%20int%29))

Comment: fill is easy. But I want to make use of the GPU when copying or blitting surface into another (or a couple of surfaces into another, e.g. I want to blit(merge) two surfaces and paste the result into 3rd ).